# Async Fetch function not being called in useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a simple async function that I want to be called when a page loads which fetches data and updates my context.

```
import { useContext } from 'react'
import { ContentSlotsContext } from '../commerce-api/contexts'

    export default async function getSlots() {
        const { slots, setSlots } = useContext(ContentSlotsContext)
        const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos');
        const data = await response.json();
        setSlots(data);
    }
```

I'm trying to call it like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    getSlots()
})
```

slots and setSlots are a setState the context is initialised with.

But it's not being called. When I call it outside of useEffect it works but infinitely loops due to constantly re-rendering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're calling `useContext` from a function that is not a react function component or a custom hook (see [the rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-from-react-functions)). There's a useful ESLint plugin [eslint-plugin-react-hooks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react-hooks) that will warn against this.

To fix the issue, you can instead pass `setSlots` as a parameter to `getSlots`:

```js
export default async function getSlots(setSlots) {
  const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos');
  const data = await response.json();
  setSlots(data);
}
```

and call `useContext` before `useEffect`, at the top level of your function component (also a [rule of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level)), with an empty dependencies array as the second argument, so the effect only fires once (see the note in the [`useEffect` docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect)):

```js
..
const { setSlots } = useContext(ContentSlotsContext);
useEffect(() => {
  getSlots(setSlots);
}, []);
..
```

Comment: Or, much simpler, use `getSlots().then(setSlots)` with the original function

Comment: Makes sense, thanks for your help. It now keeps looping and performing the fetch x amount of times, how do I stop this? Do I add a simple check in useEffect before I run getSlots?

Comment: Ah yes, there was no dependencies-array argument. If you pass it a `[]` it should work. Added it to the answer.